Negative extrusion at an angle >90 degrees
I'm making a pot for my plant where the top opening is larger than the bottom base and the top and bottom are circular (like the below picture). I used the Loft feature to connect the top and bottom circles. The only problem is that the Loft feature filled in the interior of the pot too. I thought that I could just negative extrude to get the opening back, but the taper angle is limited to 45 degrees, so I can't quite get the 106.6 degree angle I need to get the pot to look normal. I'm thinking of trying the Shell feature next, but I honestly don't know what I'm doing (this is my first time trying to CAD). Any help is appreciated!! 

How does this apply to 3D printing?

@agarza Hello! To 3D print something, you need to CAD it first, no? That's why I used the 3D Design, cad tags instead of 3D printing specifically. I should have specified that I plan on 3D printing this pot once I'm done with the design, but I figured it was self explanatory with the fusion360 cad tags and the forum :')

If you are designing something yourself, yes you need to use CAD, but anyone can download and print an STL file. Some users come here to ask questions about how to use Fusion 360 which has no relation to 3D printing. It's best to supply any and all information to help solve your particular problem. Also, Stack Exchange is not a forum but a repository of questions/answers.

@agarza I don't understand. My post is about a pot I'm CADing (it is related to 3D printing). I explained the problem I'm having and provided a sample picture of the pot I'm trying to replicate showing the >90 angle. If Stack Exchange is a repository for questions/ answers, how is my post inappropriate? I asked a question hoping for an answer and plan to post the answer if/when I figure it out in case others have a similar question later TT

I never said your post was inappropriate. If a post is made that has nothing to do with the site then it has the potential to be closed. I was asking how your post applies to 3D printing to avoid it being closed, i.e. it was for your benefit. I would also recommend you take the [tour] and visit the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

@agarza ok I'll be sure to look over the links

Using a loft for that is not ideal. You could make it work by defining both the inner and outer circles at each level, doing lofts between those and the stitching the result.
Normally, you would use a "revolve" for an item like that. Imagine cutting the pot in half and drawing one half of the resulting profile of the pot. You would then "revolve" that sketch around the center line of the pot.

@towe This worked! I ended up still lofting it but adding a sketch cross section on the interior and cut revolving it! :-)

Loft top and bottom faces together, add vertical trapezoidal cross section sketch on any side view of pot, & revolve cut 360 degrees.
